# Increasing index.max_result_window to 10000000.Issues with it?

Tags: elasticsearch

I know we can increase `max_result_window` greater than `10000`.But have read, increasing to very big numbers would cause issues.
I guess the only issue is of `JVM(Memory)`, since these many requests would go to each node, so basically each `data nodes` should be big enough to handle products greater than `max_result_window`.Also `coordinate nodes` should be much bigger than `max_result_window` since it would be handling merging of products.

Could any one help me understand what could be other issues related to increasing and not just memory.
Also Kindly correct me.
I know we should be using scroll/pagination , but my question is whats limiting factor here?

Comment: It would be nice to provide some insights into why you need to increase that setting that much...

Comment: @val for our use case , when fetching from ES ,products are greater than 1000000 across indices.

Comment: I got that part, but I'm curious why you have to fetch all products in one go?

Comment: coz , with all the data we would be creating some analytics over it.(thats why complete data is required.)

Comment: Then you need to use [scrolling](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html) or [search_after](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-search-after.html), but not the usual from/size pagination.

Comment: @val Yeah , I  know we should be using ,I just need to know why there is a limit on `max_result_window`.Is it just due to memory limitation ?

Comment: It's all explained here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/pagination.html

Comment: yup , memory issue seems, I have already explained in my question , but if we have sufficient memory then there should not be any worry?

Comment: Best way to know is to try and see your node fail... or do it the right way ;-) For your use case, I see no reason why you can't use scroll or search_after.